# Gradle - Use copy task to copy a file from outside project

Tags: gradle

I have two separate gradle projects in the following structure. I want to write a task to move the build jar from projectA to projectB's lib folder.

projectA -> c:/User/someUser/dev/projectA

projectB -> c:/User/someUser/dev/projectB

In projectA's build script, I have the following to move the generated jar from projectA's build/lib folder to projectB's lib folder.

```
task deployJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/libs/')
    into('C:/Users/someUser/dev/projectB/libs')
    include('*.jar')
}
```

I'm using absolute path but it is not working. I was hoping if someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered setting up the projects as a multi-project? You could hook them together with [includeFlat](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#includeFlat(java.lang.String[])).  What you would usually do is have projectA deploy to an artifact repository and resolve the jar in projectB through `dependencies {}` or set projectA/projectB up as a multi-project and have projectB depend on the output of projectA (also through `dependencies {}`). If you go the second route, you get nice things like projectA automatically rebuilding when necessary when you build projectB.

I don't see anything exactly wrong with what you have already.  Does it fail with an error?

Keep in mind that setting up your build with absolute paths will make it non-portable/fragile.

Comment: Yes, I have. That is what I'll ultimately end up doing once everything is setup.

So I went back to reproduce it to provide you the error message and when I did, it was working.... I guess I must have mis-typed something when I initially tired it. I copied what I had above and it worked. 

Thanks again.